# How read the data of Type IDictionary<string,EntityType> contains collection of values... how to read this item in List collection

Tags: c#, dictionary, dynamic-tables

Data looks like
[0]:[0]{[item,{item1}]}
[2]{[item,{item2}]}

[2]{[item,{item2}]}
Its like collection inside collection... I am trying to make it as list so that I can retrieve it. Any help really appreciated....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely have a look at SelectMany in Linq. From what you wrote I am not sure what you want to achieve. For reference try to analyze this code:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> {
    [1] = Enumerable.Range(1,5),
    [3] = Enumerable.Range(3, 5)
};    
var asList = dictionary.SelectMany(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value.Prepend(keyValuePair.Key));
```

Comment: Actually I have azure table where I have entries with different partition key and row key.... when I am reading all the rows from entity I am getting queryResult of type TableQuerySegment<DynamicTableEntity> which contains properties Row key, Partition key, Etag and Properties. I need to read the Properties where it contains my columns data... and convert this data into Json response